# Iterating backwards in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, iteration

I was under the impression that the following code would print out "hello world," but it doesn't print anything at all. Why?
Compiled using g++ 4.2.1 and cl++ 3.2 .

```
void iterateBackwards(){
    std::string hiThere = "dlrow olleh";
    for ( int i = hiThere.length(); i == 0; i--) {
        std::cout << hiThere[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: A for loop exits as soon as the exit condition (`i==0`) is false.

Comment: If you want to print the string out backwards, use: `std::copy(hiThere.rbegin(), hiThere.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your condition should be `i >= 0`, not `i == 0` (a `for` loop exits as soon as the condition is `false`, which is immediately the case in your example).

Also, once you fix this, you should fix the assignment to `i` as well, since the subscript operator accepts zero-based indices; this means that when `i == hiThere.length()` you would be accessing the terminator character of the string, which you probably have no interest in outputting.

This should work better:

```
void iterateBackwards(){
    std::string hiThere = "dlrow olleh";
    for ( int i = hiThere.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        std::cout << hiThere[i];
    }
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://ideone.com/stnZxJ).

Comment: The program has no undefined behavior.  He never accesses any elements at all, let alone out-of-range elements.

Comment: Okay.  But still, although the behavior is probably not what the OP is after, there would be no undefined behavior after the first fix.  `basic_string` has a special provision for `operator[]`, in order to be compatible with common c-string usage.  Accessing `hiThere[hiThere.size()]` is legal, and returns a reference to a char with the value `char()`, that may or may not be at the end of the string.  See the standard: `21.4.5/1&2`.  If you try to modify the value, that is undefined behavior, but that's not being done here.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Right. I will edit once again. Thank you

Comment: Here to help.  And annoy with pedantry.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: The only annoying thing is my ignorance :) Thank you for helping

Comment: Since we're being pedant, what happens here when the string is bigger than INT_MAX? (which the standard allows, even though it is extremely unlikely to happen in the real world) ;)

Comment: This is a very `C` answer for a `C++` question.

Answer (score 2):

1. The condition in the loop must be `i >= 0`. Otherwise the program will never enter the loop's body -- it will loop as long as `i == 0` is true and you set `i` to the length of the string.
2. `i` should be initialized with `hiThere.length() - 1`. Otherwise you will have undefined behavior -- strings and arrays in C++ are 0-indexed, i.e. 1st index is `0` and the last is `size - 1` (so `hiThere[hiThere.length() - 1]` is the last element of `hiThere`).
3. You should look into C++ iterators:

   ```
   void iterateBackwards(){
       std::string hiThere = "dlrow olleh";
       for (auto it = hiThere.crbegin(); it != hiThere.crend() ; ++it) {
           std::cout << *it;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

@AndyProwl already has given a solution which I'll copy here for easier comparison with mine:

```
std::string hiThere = "dlrow olleh";
for ( int i = hiThere.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    std::cout << hiThere[i];
}
```

For the sake of completeness, you could also write it that way (and it is worth knowing that form since you're likely to encounter it -- note that it is *exactly* equivalent to Andy's solution):

```
std::string hiThere = "dlrow olleh";
for (size_t i = hiThere.length(); i--; ) {
    std::cout << hiThere[i];
}
```

A few comments:

- We can now use an unsigned (size_t) index since we don't need negative values any more. This is interesting, because what would happen in Andy's solution if your string was longer than INT_MAX? (which is very unlikely to happen, I'll grant you that, but still...) This form solves this small (actually, pedantic) dilemma.
- The termination condition and the afterthought are merged together, so the afterthought is left empty.
- Unlike most `for` loops we are used to, here it is really important to use the post-decrement operator rather than the usual pre-decrement one, the whole thing relies on it.

But honestly I prefer @woytaz's solution with iterators, just because it is more consistent with the rest of the STL.

Answer (score 0):

Also, your condition in the for loop should be

```
i >= 0
```

instead of

```
i == 0
```

This is because the for loop will iterate as long as that is true and it will be FALSE if you use i==0.